# Delete swap partition, create in other drive allocated to ntfs

Tags: partitioning, swap, memory-usage

I currently have 8GB of swap in /dev/sda5 and want to delete those and create a new swap partition in my other drive /dev/sdb with 30GB.

**1.** Is this effective, regarding system speed?

**2.** Is this safe to do?

This last drive is allocated as follows:

```
NAME                             MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                                8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1                             8:1    0 230.6G  0 part /
├─sda2                             8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5                             8:5    0   7.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb                                8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sdb2                             8:18   0   1.8T  0 part /media/andre/B2F8C9A0
```

R/W speeds:

```
sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   28256 MB in  2.00 seconds = 14142.30 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 944 MB in  3.00 seconds = 314.26 MB/sec
sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb:
 Timing cached reads:   27300 MB in  2.00 seconds = 13663.28 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 464 MB in  3.00 seconds = 154.58 MB/sec

sudo lsblk -f
NAME                             FSTYPE LABEL MOUNTPOINT
sda                                           
├─sda1                           ext4         /
├─sda2                                        
└─sda5                           swap         [SWAP]
sdb                                           
└─sdb2                           ntfs         /media/andre/B2F8C9A0F8C962E9
```

Tried gparted but am not sure of the steps to take to do this. Can someone suggest what to do, step by step?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? For speed or space? Can you measure the read and write speed of the two drives? Or do you need the extra space for the root partition '/'? Are you hibernating the system? If not, you probably need less space for swap, maybe only 2 GB. - You must match the UUID of the drive with the string listed in the file /etc/fstab. And you see the uuid with this command: 'sudo lsblk -f' (without quotes). - Editing partitions is always risky, but this operation is not as risky as editing the root partition. You should always *backup* your personal files.

Comment: @sudodus Need to do this to run a specific program which I know needs just under +30GB. R/W speed seems to be basically the same:

sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   28256 MB in  2.00 seconds = 14142.30 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 944 MB in  3.00 seconds = 314.26 MB/sec
sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 Timing cached reads:   27300 MB in  2.00 seconds = 13663.28 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 464 MB in  3.00 seconds = 154.58 MB/sec

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one swap partition. Create the new swap partition in the other drive (with gparted), check the UUID with

```
sudo lsblk -f
```

and create a line in the file

```
/etc/fstab
```

that looks pretty much like the current line for /dev/sda5 but pointing to this new swap partition. It will be activated at reboot or manually with

```
sudo swapon -a
```

(when it is found in /etc/fstab).